# Wordpress - Custom post type "all posts" listing taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom post type with several taxonomies.
The thing is that's listing all taxonomies in the custom post type's listing page (All pages button) and I would like to choose which ones to display and which ones not. 
Googled a lot, but can't find a way to solve this.

Anyone knows wich functions/flags are necesary to let wordpress know if I want X taxonomy to be shown in the listing page of the  custom post it's related to?

Sorry if I don't add any code, I believe it's not necesary since it's a teorical question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
When declaring a taxonomy, these are the args you have to pass.

```
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'query_var'                  => 'vehicle_fuel_type',
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
);
```

show_admin_column declares if the taxonomy should be shown on the post's listing page or not.

Hope someone finds it useful